# Windows 8 bengali unicode character display

Tags: windows

I am using windows 8.It shows bengali character 'র' as 'য়' .Is there any way to fix this?
[image]

Below is an image that shows the correct display should be 'ভারত' but it shows as 'ভায়ত'

Comment: File a bug with Microsoft. Other than that, I doubt there's anything you can do.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the **Bangla (Bangladesh)** [LIP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads-for-windows-32490f9b-01ee-c13e-b2af-b5057c2d34e8), try **Bengali (India)** instead (or vice versa).

If that doesn't help, as mentioned above your best bet would be to file a bug report with MS. [Michael Kaplan of MS](https://web.archive.org/web/20131031155523/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/michkap/) might also be able to shed some light on this issue.